# Passing a 2D Array to CUDA Device and Using it

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, cuda

I have a problem related to CUDA. I create a array which is 2D with :

```
char **WordMatrix = new char*[N]; // M and N set by the user
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
{
    WordMatrix[i] = new char[M];
}
```

I fill the array with a loop. After that where my problem is lying : I can't managed to allocate the memory in device and copy from host to device.

I saw other questions related to this but I did not understand the logic.
Like in this topic : https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/410182/double-pointer-allocation/ or in here.

I want to understand how to do it with an code example which uses **cudaMemcpy and cudaMalloc and 2D Array** also explanation of why we need supporting(if you use the approach in the link) pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is CUDA accepts only linearized 2D arrays, so really a 1D array.

```
int  *my_array = new int[height*width];
for (int h = 0; h < height; h++){
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        my_array[width * h + w] = value;
}
```

You can then copy that to device memory as in the other answer.

Also, this question has more info: 
[Allocate 2D Array on Device Memory in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047369/allocate-2d-array-on-device-memory-in-cuda?rq=1).

Comment: "CUDA accepts only linearized 2D arrays"  This is not correct. CUDA can work with 2D arrays.  The marked duplicate question demonstrates this.  However it's usually not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your 2D array in one piece `new char[N*M]`
2. Allocate the same amout of memory on GPU `cudaMalloc(... sizeof(char)*N*M)`
3. Copy your CPU memory (1.) to GPU (2.) with `cudaMemcpy(... hostToDevice)`

Comment: Isn't this kind of creating 1D array?